# sending multiple lines of linux to PHP exec()

Tags: php, linux, unix, command-line

I'm trying to process multiple unix calls with `exec()` but the first command seems to have no effect on the second:

```
exec('cd ../my/new/directory/');
echo exec('pwd')' //directory the PHP is in. not the new directory/
```

What's the deal here?

Answer (score 3):

When you call PHP's `exec()`, PHP will `fork` a new process, and `exec` (Unix syscall) the `cd` command. The parent process (PHP) will then `wait` on the child process to complete.

Thus, the `cd` *only takes effect in the child process*. After `cd` returns, your parent process (PHP) is in the same state it was in before.

Answer (score 0):

combine then and seperate with ';' to define the end of a statement
$x = shell_exec('cd ../my/new/directory/;pwd');
echo $x;